# ASP.NET Core 5 - Force Ocelot Routing to use URL Encoding

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ocelot

I have a little issue with Ocelot Gateway v17.

I'm using URL Encoding to pass some parameter to controller. Like this:

```
https://localhost:44350/api/analytics/alarms/RD-A-001%2F1/1
```

Testing in my laptop, works fine, but in the server (IIS), Ocelot sends the parameter with URL Decoding. Like this:

```
http://localhost/analytics.api/alarms/RD-A-001/1/1
```

There is any configuration to Ocelot to force to send parameters using URL Encoding?

Regards,
Gustavo

Comment: I thinks I need to configure URL Rewrite Module with UNENCODED_URL, but I'm not sure how can I do it. :-/